# A randomly selected purchaser has a router that needs repair under warranty. what is the probability that the router is brand 1?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A store sells four brands of routers.  The least expensive brand 1 accounts for 40% of the sales.  The other brands (in order of their price) have the following percentages of sales:
2, 30%; 3, 20%; and 4, 10%. The respective probabilities of needing repair during warranty are 0.1, 0.05, 0.03,  and 0.02, for brands 1, 2, 3, and 4.

A randomly selected purchaser has a router that needs repair under warranty. what is the probability that the router is brand 1?

do I just multiply probability of B1 sales and needing repair together? (0.4 x 0.1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you heard of Bayes Theorem?

Comment: are you suggesting I compute Pr(B1| needs repair)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is asked. Make an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HINT*

With $B_i$ = Brand *i*, and $R$ = needing repair ,

you need to find $P(B_i|R) = \dfrac{P(B_i)*P(R|B_i)}{\Sigma[ P(B_i)*P(R|B_i)]}$

*FURTHER HINT*

A commonsense way which in effect is using Bayes' Rule is to assume that, say $1000$ pieces have been manufactured, and compute numbers needing repair for each brand

Brand $B_1$: $400$ pieces, $40$ needing repair
Brand $B_2$: $300$ pieces, $15$ needing repair,
and so on

What fraction of pieces needing repair are from brand $B_1$ ?

> Using the formula given in the first part, answer will be

> $\dfrac{0.4*0.1}{0.4*0.1+0.3*0.05+ 0.2*0.03+0.1*0.02}$

Comment: I tried using Bayes theorem ((0.4x0.1)(0.4)) / ((0.4x0.1)(0.4) + (0.6)(0.0176)) = 0.60

Comment: Not correct, see "further hint" for a simple way to understand.

Comment: oh I see what I did wrong I put all the notb1's into one spot instead of adding each chance separately. This probability stuff is brutal thanks for your help <3

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Going by the formula provided by in true blue anil in his answer, I believe the probability should be $0.63$.